# Trying to install sharepoint prerequisites from powershell within workflow

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

## EDIT:

This question was asked without a full understanding of what the .exe actually returns. The code snippet actually returned what it was supposed to.

## Original Question:

Code:

```
workflow parallelPrereqInstall{
param ($serverNames, $outputFile, $installFilePath)
Function Log-Write([string]$logString){
    $logTime = Get-Date -Format "MM-dd-yyyy_hh-mm-ss"
    $s = "$logTime      $logString";
    Add-Content $Using:outputFile -Value $s
    Write-Host $logString
}
foreach -parallel($server in $serverNames){
  $SPPrereqsInstalled = InlineScript {
        $installSPPrereqs = {
            $fullPath = "$args\prerequisiteinstaller.exe"
            $prereqResult = Start-Process -FilePath $fullPath -ArgumentList "/unattended" -Verb RunAs -Wait -WindowStyle Maximized -PassThru
            return $prereqResult.ExitCode
        }
        $user = "domain\admin"
        $pass = "password"
        $securePass = ConvertTo-SecureString $pass -AsPlainText -Force
        $cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $user, $securePass
        Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Using:server -ScriptBlock $installSPPrereqs -ArgumentList $Using:installFilePath -Credential $cred -Authentication Credssp
    }
}
```

I always get back a `-1` from the `$prereqResults` and it seems to install something, then just errors out, whereas it should run again and/or give me a different exit code. I do not believe that I am getting the correct exit code.

If I don't specify the ExitCode property, the prereqResults returns as this:

```
@{Path=; Company=; CPU=0.0625; FileVersion=; ProductVersion=; Description=;     Product=; __NounName=Process; PSComputerName=localhost;     RunspaceId=a62e33ea-5f4c-4cae-85a4-d1426efacced;     PSShowComputerName=True;     PSSourceJobInstanceId=b2624e9f-5584-4874-a5b3-a9745f95bf42; ExitCode=-1; HasExited=True; ExitTime=03/20/2017 13:12:31;           Handle=2504;     SafeHandle=Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeProcessHandle; Id=2980;     MachineName=.; PrivilegedProcessorTime=00:00:00.0625000;         StartInfo=System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo; StartTime=03/20/2017 13:12:30;     SynchronizingObject=; Total
ProcessorTime=00:00:00.0625000; UserProcessorTime=00:00:00;     EnableRaisingEvents=False; Site=; Container=}
```

Can someone help me figure out how to run and return the exit code properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Write-Output $prereqResult and check if property name is same as "ExitCode" also try to Write-Output $prereqResult.PSSourceJobInstanceId .

If it displaying properly push it to a variable and return the variable or Use  select-string -pattern "ExitCode"

Hope it works